# List of countries in native language

Tags: iphone, ios, locale, country

I'm using a webservice which provides me a list of countries to choose from as 2 letters ('us' for USA, 'es' for Spain etc.).

I need to present it to the user and send back the selection.

Is there an API on iOS to convert the country code to a country name - based on the current language? I know I can have a static mapping of codes to countries, but I would like to support other languages than English.

For example, I would like to display "Spain" for 'es' when using english locale and "Espanya" when using spanish locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this, maybe it suits your needs too:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
[locale release];
```

Comment: actually, this is even better since I can get additional information about the country. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one, but I suggest you to build your own solution. Free APIs give you limits that maybe limit your app usage [Link](http://www.geognos.com/geo/en/world-countries-API.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently it's easier than I though: I'm posting the answer if anyone else will have the same problem:

```
NSString* name=[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:@"ca"];
```

That's it :)